# Excel VBA - Multiple Column Sort with Subsections

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an Excel macro in VBA to take data that is currently sorted based on date and sort it into multiple groupings.

The data set can be thought of as

[image: this].

Basically, 4 columns with client information currently sorted by date.

I want to be able to do a multi-tiered sort that is different depending on the section. So, first all the information would be sorted A-Z based on "Section".

Then, for section 1, the information needs to be sorted by subsection (A-Z), then by date (oldest to newest).

But for section 2, the information needs to be sorted just by date (oldest to newest).

For section 3, the information needs to be sorted by client (A-Z), then Subsection (A-Z), then date (oldest to newest).

For section 4, the information needs to be sorted by subsection (A-Z), then client (A-Z), then date (oldest to newest).

With our example data that sort would end up looking like

[image: this].

I have tried using the sort function but I am unable to figure out how to define the data. I created a VBA using Columns.sort with keys for each column, but that does not seem to allow me to sort each section differently.

Comment: Use `Get & Transform` aka `Power Query`. Group by Section; then you can sort each section according to the applicable rules.

Comment: Please share the code (as text) that references the table (range) and sorts it by date so we can build on it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort data on "Section", then sort each section.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim rData As Range, arrData, arrKey
    Dim i As Long, Dic
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim sKey As String
    'Sheet6.[a1].CurrentRegion.Copy [a1]
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet
    Set rData = oSht.[a1].CurrentRegion
    rData.Sort key1:=oSht.Cells(2, 2), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    arrData = rData.Value
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = Trim(rData(i, 2))
        If Not Dic.exists(sKey) Then
            Set Dic(sKey) = oSht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 4)
        Else
            Set Dic(sKey) = Union(Dic(sKey), oSht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 4))
        End If
    Next i
    arrKey = Dic.keys
    If Dic.Count = 4 Then
        Set rData = Dic(arrKey(0))
        rData.Sort key1:=rData.Cells(1, 3), order1:=xlAscending, _
            key2:=rData.Cells(1, 1), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Set rData = Dic(arrKey(1))
        rData.Sort key1:=rData.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Set rData = Dic(arrKey(2))
        rData.Sort key1:=rData.Cells(1, 4), order1:=xlAscending, _
            key2:=rData.Cells(1, 3), order2:=xlAscending, _
            key3:=rData.Cells(1, 1), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Set rData = Dic(arrKey(3))
        rData.Sort key1:=rData.Cells(1, 3), order1:=xlAscending, _
            key2:=rData.Cells(1, 4), order2:=xlAscending, _
            key3:=rData.Cells(1, 1), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create three new columns to hold calculated sort sub keys. Then the formulas would be like this (assuming the first row of data starts at A2:

SortSubKey1: =CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"Section 1","Section 2","Section 3","Section 4"},0),C2,TEXT(A2,"yyyymmdd"),D2,C2)

SortSubKey2: =CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"Section 1","Section 2","Section 3","Section 4"},0),TEXT(A2,"yyyymmdd"),"",C2,D2)

SortSubKey3: =CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"Section 1","Section 2","Section 3","Section 4"},0),"","",TEXT(A2,"yyyymmdd"),TEXT(A2,"yyyymmdd"))

Then you would get something like this which then you can use the normal multi-column sort to sort by Section, SortSubKey1, SortSubKey2, SortSubKey3:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Section", type text}, {"Sub Section", type text}, {"Client", type text}}),

/*Group by Section
    then Sort according to secion*/
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Section"}, {
        {"Sorted", (t)=> 
            if t[Section]{0} = "Section 1"
                then Table.Sort(t, {{"Sub Section", Order.Ascending},{"Date",Order.Ascending}})
            else if t[Section]{0} = "Section 2"
                then Table.Sort(t,{{"Date",Order.Ascending}})
            else if t[Section]{0} = "Section 3"
                then Table.Sort(t, {{"Client", Order.Ascending},{"Sub Section", Order.Ascending},{"Date", Order.Ascending}})
            else if t[Section]{0} = "Section 4"
                then Table.Sort(t,{{"Sub Section", Order.Ascending},{"Client",Order.Ascending},{"Date",Order.Ascending}})
            else t,
        type table [Date=nullable date, Section=nullable text, Sub Section=nullable text, Client=nullable text]}}),

/*Sort by column 1 section    
    Then Remove first column and expand the subtables*/
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Section", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Section"}),
    #"Expanded Sorted" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Sorted", {"Date", "Section", "Sub Section", "Client"}, {"Date", "Section", "Sub Section", "Client"})
    
in
    #"Expanded Sorted"
```

***Source Data***
[image]

***Sorted***
[image]